# socket io load failed

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

Hi I am quite new to socket io, and I am trying to make a simple chat. The problem is that I keep on getting errors for failed loading. I can't figure it out what is wrong with my code. I am using the code from: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

[image]

```
<ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
        <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.0.0/socket.io.js"><script/></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io("http://192.168.88.152:3000");

        var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
        var form = document.getElementById('form');
        var input = document.getElementById('input');

        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (input.value) {
            socket.emit('chat message', input.value);
            input.value = '';
            }
        });

        socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            item.textContent = msg;
            messages.appendChild(item);
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
    </script>
```

The code for backent:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html.php');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('user disconnected');
    });
  });

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
      console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
  });

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
      io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
  });

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In this link It hasn't serve static file in socket.io example. So you can fix this error by using script as cdn:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.0.0/socket.io.js"><script/>
```

or download cdn file and serve it your file with express: [link](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now the only problem is that I need to find out why no messages are going through. If you want the html code is in the original post.

Comment: @Blinker  ok share it

Comment: Ive updated the original post it is there

Comment: Can you share backend?

Comment: Just updated the post.

Comment: read this [link](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/)

Comment: So if I understand I have to give a url to the socket io to witch it will send messages. Example: const io("http://192.168.88.152:3000")

Comment: @Blinker yeah  :)

Comment: I am sorry to keep on asking you questions. I have added the link to witch the chat page has to send the message (http://192.168.88.152: 3000) but the message never gets to the server. I have updated the code if you whant to see what I did.

Comment: Your code looks correct, I can't think of an idea right now

Comment: If i go to 192.168.88.152:3000 it will work fine but if i try using the page where the chat is chat.html.php it is tying to send the message to the url of chat.html.php

Comment: I can show you on discord if you whant